# F# - FSI- Load source file "Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException"

Tags: f#, f#-interactive

I have updated Visual Studio Community 2019 to Version 16.11.4 and when I try to load a source file (i.e.: Library1.fs) into the FSI environment (trough Alt+Enter or writing the #load command inside the FSI environment inside VISUAL STUDIO), I get the Stack Overflow Exception error:

```
Microsoft (R) F# Interactive versione 11.4.2.0 per F# 5.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti sono riservati.
    
Per informazioni, digitare #help;;

#load "C:\Users\GianLuca\Source\Repos\x\x\Library1.fs";;

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
Session termination detected.
```

This happen everytime I try to “Load” any source file, event an empty source file!!

NOTE: I’m using F-Sharp Library (.NET Framework 4.72), but the same occurs with CLASS LIBRARY (.NTE STANDARd or .NET CORE)

NOTE: if I lunch “dotnet fsi” from the command prompt (cmd) - outside form Visual Studio - and I try to “Load” the same files, it works fine (no Stack Overflow Exception!).

[image]

NOTE: I have launched the REPAIR action from the VISUAL STUDIO INSTALLER, but the problem persists.

How I can resolve it? I’m confused.
It seems a problem of F# INTERACTIVE inside Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.4

Many thanks in advance!

(See also: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/F---FSI--Load-source-file-Process-is-t/1550593)

Comment: I confirm that up to Visual Studio Community Version 18.11.2, the load command works fine ( same F# 11.3.2.0, same Framework 4.8.04084).

Comment: Problem still persists on Visual Studio Community version 16.11.5.

Comment: FWIW, I just tried this on VS Community v16.11.5 and it worked fine. `Microsoft (R) F# Interactive version 11.4.2.0 for F# 5.0`

Comment: Hi  brianberns, I have updated VISUAL STUDIO COMMUNITY in No. 3 differt PC of differnt users and settings, and once I have updated to VS Community v16.11.5 I get the same problem (with previous version everytingh works fines). I will try to UNINSTALL and REINSTALL ... but I'm not so confident that this will work! I hope ..

Comment: Hi @brianberns, I have removed ALL Visual Studio Files, delete all folders inside my Hard Disk and reinstalled Visual Studio Community from ZERO, but the problem still persists: when I try to lunch the '#load' command into F# Interactive inside Visual Studio, I get the same error 'Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException. Session termination detected.'

Comment: UPDATE: with Visual Studio Community 2019, Version 16.11.6, the above reported "failure" has been resolved (F# Interactive still in version 11.4.2.0 - F# 5.0). Thanks to the Team of VS!